# Error in creating generator for 'carrierwave_backgrounder:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, mime-types, carrierwave-backgrounder

I am creating a generator for the 'carrierwave_backgrounder:install' to process my image in S3. However, I am stuck in a problem

1. When I just use  `gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'`, I am getting the error

   `Could not find generator 'carrierwave_backgrounder:install'. 
   Maybe you meant 'rspec:install', 'exception_notification:install' or 'active_record:model`
2. When I use  `gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', git: 'https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder'` as per the suggestions given everwhere and run bundle install or bundle update, I am getting the error

   `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
   In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
   mime-types (= 3.3)

   In Gemfile:
   carrierwave-base64 (= 2.6.1) was resolved to 2.6.1, which depends on
     mime-types (~> 3.0)
   carrierwave_backgrounder was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
   mime-types (~> 2.99)`

and my bundle-update is also not able to resolve the error. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `'carrierwave_backgrounder',git:'https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder'` to 
`gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', github: 'lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder', ref: 'bff7bc3954b9184157812f948b9a6a4f64ff36d3'` solves the problem.

Thanks to the post : https://qiita.com/oshimaryo/items/b23779c32b904bb2ebda